# Blender API - Repair meshes, similar to Windows 3D Viewer?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, stl

I have a question about repairing an stl, particularly after a Bollean union. I've been working on a script that allows me to make customizable game pieces for 3d printing. It involves combining a number of meshes (Usually a ground object, walls, windows, rocks, etc.). I've been playing with different ways to combine the objects into one so they can be exported and 3d printed. The trouble is, something is always a little off after combining the objects. When I use a Boolean union (usually with the booltool addon), I almost always get some non-manifold geometry when I import the combined object into my slicer.
Just combining the objects (ctrl+j) works, but I usually get intersecting meshes that can cause problems when printing.

Now, when I open those stl's in Windows 3D Viewer, I get a warning that there are problems with the mesh and 3D Viewer will automatically repair it. When I load the repaired file into my slicer, everything looks great!

So my question is, does anyone know what windows 3D Viewer actually does when you click "repair"? And more importantly, is there anything similar in Blender?

**Edit: Here are the pictures

1. When I first load the model in Cura
2. Loading the model in 3D Viewer (After which I click repair)
3. The repaired model in Cura (no problems)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you post a screen of the mesh before / after repair so we can see what it does ?

Comment: Yes, I just added them to the post